# jQuery serialize converts all spaces to plus

Tags: jquery, serialization, space

Currently, everywhere I use serialize I have to use it like this:

```
.serialize().replace(/\+/g,'%20');
```

otherwise any spaces in the form data will be coverted to +'s. Is there a setting that can make this the default.

Answer (score 4):

For fun, here's an alternative that doesn't use a temporary variable:

```
$.fn.serializeAndEncode = function() {
    return $.map(this.serializeArray(), function(val) {
        return [val.name, encodeURIComponent(val.value)].join('=');
    }).join('&');
};

$("#formToSerialize").serializeAndEncode();
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was doing on my own.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same thing.
The solution Terry gave, with escape(), doesn't work. The = and & are getting encoded (we don't want that) and the + are still there.

What I did is creating my own function to serialize:

```
var QueryString = "";
$(selector).each(function(index) {
    if(QueryString != "") QueryString += "&";
    QueryString += $(this).get(0).id + "=" + encodeURIComponent( $(this).val() );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't believe there is a default, you will need to encode the string in [one of these ways](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/).

Though you could create your own plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.serializeAndEncode = function() {
    return escape(this.serialize());
}

$(myForm).serializeAndEncode();
```

Comment: Please don't use `escape`. It has been [deprecated for many years](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_functions(Obsoleted_above_JavaScript_1.5) and should be replaced with `encodeURIComponent` like in Matt Roy's example.