# How to strip all whitespaces (like spaces, tabs, newlines) from jQuery Ajax Data?

Tags: jquery, serialization, tabs, whitespace, strip

How to strip all whitespaces (like spaces, tabs, newlines) from jQuery Ajax Data?

```
data: $('#field1, #field2, #field3').serialize()
```

Comment: These questions may help you [serialize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025594/jquery-serialize-converts-all-spaces-to-plus) and [replaceAll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507056/replace-all-whitespace-characters)

Comment: @Xeon: Already read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
var array = $('#field1, #field2, #field3').serializeArray();
$.each(array, function(i,o){
    o.value = o.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
})
....
data: array
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j4zyR/)

Comment: Thank you! Doesn't `\s` cover all whitespaces?

Comment: Thanks again! Unfortunately I can't vote up your answer yet as it requires 15 reputation.

Comment: Additional question: Is it possible to do it all in one line?

Comment: not as far as I know... if the inputs are not properly sanitized this is the only safe way I'm seeing

Comment: @simplethings another solution you can try is `data: $('#field1, #field2, #field3').serialize().replace(/\s/g, '')`

Comment: Doesn't work. Spaces e.g. are converted into `+` by `serialize()`.

Comment: @simplethings in that case I don't see any other way for now